# Git shows two branches as being the same while xcode shows them as different

Tags: ios, git, xcode9

I am having an issue where I have merged a branch into master from the Git CLI, but Xcode (9.0) shows that one of my views in the main.storyboard has different constraints on master than on rollback (the branch I merged into master). This is a problem because the constraints are the changes I need to be committed to master, and built to the Appstore for that matter.

I have tried to merge rollback into master again and Git tells me that it is already up to date. When I switch to branch "rollback" it shows one set of constraints on my view in Xcode and Xcode shows another on the master branch.

Does anyone know why Xcode is not keeping the same version as Git appears to be? How can this be rectified?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xcode generally messes sometimes when you push something to Git, especially incases where the file is a storyboard.

One of the ways forward would be to take a new clone of the Master branch in a new project folder on your mac. Put in your main.storyboard with the changes you want again in the new taken clone of the project and commit/ push it in. If it still shows some conflict keep your version of the main.storyboard (The one with the changes you want to incorporate). Should work fine. Had similar issues in the past, this solution generally did it for me.